# zsh in Emacs output junk characters

Tags: emacs, zsh, emacs23

No matter I use term or ansi-term to start zsh in Emacs, I encounter this problem, whenever I input commands, the output will have some junk characters like:

```
[ruby-1.9.2] ~ pwd
2;pwd1;pwd/Users/tyraeltong
```

the `2;pwd1;pwd` is screwing the output, don't know whether others are experiencing same problem? I found a similar thread here [Getting Emacs ansi-term and Zsh to play nicely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367442/getting-emacs-ansi-term-and-zsh-to-play-nicely) but by `[[ $TERM == eterm-color ]] && export TERM=xterm` I still see the junk characters.

Comment: It's a problem caused directly or indirectly by something in your `.zshrc`. Probably a bad prompt setting, or one that makes unwarranted assumptions about the terminal it's running in. Post your `.zshrc`.

Comment: Actually I didn't make any customization in my .zshrc, instead, I just using .oh-my-zsh: https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh

Answer (score 6):

Emacs doesn't play nice with ZLE, so I have this in my ~/.zshrc:

```
if [[ -n ${INSIDE_EMACS} ]]; then
    # This shell runs inside an Emacs *shell*/*term* buffer.
    prompt walters
    unsetopt zle
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but with this setting, I still see the extra bits, e.g:

2;LS -G -lhF1;lstotal 72

Comment: Hm, is INSIDE_EMACS set?  E.g., do `M-x shell` in emacs, and `echo $INSIDE_EMACS` in there.  It should output something like "24.0.97.1,comint".

If not, then that variable isn't set by emacs (maybe because your emacs is too old?!).  In that case, you could change the test to `[[ ${TERM} == "dumb" ]]` which should also work.

Comment: Ah, and you might also need this in your ~/.emacs:

`(add-hook 'shell-mode-hook 'ansi-color-for-comint-mode-on)`

Comment: humm, echo $INSIDE_EMACS will output something like "]2;echo 24.0.92.1,comint]1;echo24.0.92.1,comint". I also added the (add-hook) into the .emacs file, still see extra bits... BTW, which way are you using zsh under Emacs? is it "term", or "shell"?

Comment: I use `M-x shell` and the `add-hook` above only works for that.  After doing `M-x shell`, a `ls --color` should list files in colored.  If you still get the raw color escape sequences, there's something wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Found the solution [in the related post mentioned earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10050104/943531)

In a nutshell, in emacs `M-x package-install` and install multi-term. `M-x multi-term` kicks off a shell, with all the bells & whistles oh-my-zsh has to offer

Answer (score 0):

It could be an erronious PROMPT_COMMAND that has bash syntax.  Try:

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND=""
```

and see if that helps.